# Changing the first column depending of the remaining ones

Tags: r, replace

I would like to change the group (`S1`...`S5`) in the `Var1` column to depict the largest number in `Freq` column as `S1`, the second largest as `S2` and so on. Please realize that the factors in this case are the numbers in the `Position` column. Thus, for the `Position == 26998698`, for example, we will finish with `1587` as `S1` in the `output` instead `S3`, `340` as `S2` in the `output` instead `S4` and so on.

```
df <- 'Var1 Freq Position
S1    1 26998698
S2  125 26998698
S3 1587 26998698
S4  340 26998698
S5    8 26998698
S1   68 27252684
S2  703 27252684
S3  913 27252684
S4  293 27252684
S5   58 27252684
S1    7 27209738
S2  383 27209738
S3 1425 27209738
S4  239 27209738
S5    6 27209738'
df<- read.table(text=df, header=T)
```

My expected `output`

```
output <- 'Var1 Freq Position
S5    1 26998698
S3  125 26998698
S1 1587 26998698
S2  340 26998698
S4    8 26998698
S4   68 27252684
S2  703 27252684
S1  913 27252684
S3  293 27252684
S5   58 27252684
S4    7 27209738
S2  383 27209738
S1 1425 27209738
S3  239 27209738
S5    6 27209738'
output<- read.table(text=output, header=T)
```

Some ideas to perform that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an approach using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Position) %>% 
  mutate(Var1 = Var1[dense_rank(desc(Freq))])
#Source: local data frame [15 x 3]
#Groups: Position [3]
#
#     Var1  Freq Position
#   (fctr) (int)    (int)
#1      S5     1 26998698
#2      S3   125 26998698
#3      S1  1587 26998698
#4      S2   340 26998698
#5      S4     8 26998698
#6      S4    68 27252684
#...
```

After grouping the data by `Position`, we compute the `dense_rank` (i.e. minimum rank without gaps) of `Freq` and use that to index `Var1`. Since we want to actually compute the opposite of a `min_rank` without gaps, we use `desc(Freq)`, i.e. in descending order.

Answer (score 4):

just another option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, Var1:= Var1[frank(-Freq, ties.method="dense")], by = Position]

#    Var1 Freq Position
# 1:   S5    1 26998698
# 2:   S3  125 26998698
# 3:   S1 1587 26998698
# 4:   S2  340 26998698
# 5:   S4    8 26998698
# 6:   S4   68 27252684
# 7:   S2  703 27252684
# 8:   S1  913 27252684
# 9:   S3  293 27252684
#10:   S5   58 27252684
#11:   S4    7 27209738
#12:   S2  383 27209738
#13:   S1 1425 27209738
#14:   S3  239 27209738
#15:   S5    6 27209738
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg thanks for letting me know, I never used it before!